# How do I get a NextAuth user session on subdomains?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have an authorization page that is located on the domain auth.localhost:3000/login

But the problem is that after the user is logged in, I can't get data about him if I switch to another subdomain,

Example:

- **auth.localhost:3000** - ✅ **(authenticated)**
- **any.localhost:3000** - ❌ **(not authenticated)**
- **localhost:3000** - ❌ **(not authenticated)**

```js
auth.ts

"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.16"
"next": "14.1.4"


import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GitHub from "next-auth/providers/github";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "./prisma";

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  providers: [GitHub],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  redirectProxyUrl: "http://auth.localhost:3000/api/auth"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it only works for only one subdomain is that `next auth` by default sets the cookies on the domain that the signIn has performed on. To change the default behavior and give it a custom domain (e.g. domain with empty subdomain which means all subdomains `.my-site.com`) while using next auth version 5 we should config the cookies' options like so:

```js
const nextAuthUrl = process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL

NextAuth({
    cookies: {
        sessionToken: {
            name: `${nextAuthUrl.startsWith('https://') ? "__Secure-": ""}next-auth.session-token`,
            options: {
                domain: nextAuthUrl === "localhost" ? "." + nextAuthUrl : "." + new URL(nextAuthUrl).hostname, // support all subdomains
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                path: '/',
                secure: nextAuthUrl.startsWith('https://'),
            }
        }
    }
})
```

You might also need to config other cookies as well depending on your use case. you can read more about it in the official documentation: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#cookies

**EDIT:**

I searched more in next auth's github discussions and looks like some people already had this issue. The solution is here: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4089#discussioncomment-2297717

In short: You should set another dummy domain like a real one instead of just localhost (e.g. `localhost.home` or `dev.home` instead of `localhost`). Note that it's better to use a unique domain so it won't be a problem in the future if you open a website that its domain or its API's domain is common with your local host name

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the cookie just isn't saved ```js "domain: '.localhost'"```

I can't find an example with the next-auth@beta version anywhere.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I just updated the code and fixed it for beta version. however I'm still not sure if the `.` is necessary. If the dot didn't help try setting the domain without `.` If it is possible, give me the result. I want to know it :)

Comment: If I specify any value other than ".auth.localhost" in the domain, such as "localhost" or ".localhost", then cookies will not be set at all.

Comment: @AinurYarulin I updated the answer. try adding a real-like domain to your localhost in the `host` file.